# random_shuffle() works on windows but doesnt compile on linux

Tags: c++, linux

```
int delta[4][2] = {{0,1},{1,0},{0,-1},{-1,0}};
random_shuffle(&delta[0],&delta[4]);
```

Compile Error:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_algobase.h: In function 'void std::swap(_Tp&, _Tp&) [with _Tp = int [2]]':
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_algobase.h:127:   instantiated from 'static void std::__iter_swap<true>::iter_swap(_ForwardIterator1, _ForwardIterator2) [with _ForwardIterator1 = int (*)[2], _ForwardIterator2 = int (*)[2]]'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_algobase.h:163:   instantiated from 'void std::iter_swap(_ForwardIterator1, _ForwardIterator2) [with _ForwardIterator1 = int (*)[2], _ForwardIterator2 = int (*)[2]]'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_algo.h:1906:   instantiated from 'void std::random_shuffle(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator) [with _RandomAccessIterator = int (*)[2]]'main.cpp:150:   instantiated from here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_algobase.h:97: error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_algobase.h:98: error:    ISO C++ forbids assignment of arrays
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_algobase.h:99: error: ISO C++ forbids assignment of arrays
```

Same piece of code compiles on Windows g++.

Comment: `random_shuffle` has been approved to be removed from C++. Don't use it.

Comment: are there any alternatives i can use?

Comment: Yes, `std::shuffle`, assuming you have C++11 support. Really, GCC 4.1.2 is extremely outdated, though. You're also trying to shuffle arrays, which won't work.

Comment: @ÖmerFarukIrmak But this won't fix this particular problem. The code doesn't look like legal C++, so it shouldn't compile.

Comment: @juanchopanza what do you mean by not legal? This is the part that concerns my question, not the whole thing

Comment: @ÖmerFarukIrmak I mean it is not legal C++03, but there's a work-around that makes it work in C++11 (see answer below.)

Answer (score 2):

`std::random_shuffle` works by swapping. Swapping (normally) requires assignment. But arrays are not assignable. In C++11, there is a specialization of `std::swap` for arrays which doesn't use direct assignment. So you need to enable C++11 in order for your code to work. Add the compiler option `-std=c++11` (if your gcc version supports it).